# Android App not closing when killing main activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, launch

I have an App that has a Main (root) activity which is a splash screen and launches a menu activity through an intent. The problem is when I am in the menu and press the back button it goes back to my splash screen as it should, but when I press the back button again to exit the app it closes my splash screen activity and goes back to the menu activity. At this point I can press the back button a third time which then appears to fully close the app. I believe the solution may to to use some launch mode configuration. Any ideas?

Comment: what code you have done so far? how can come to know whats the exact problem?

Comment: Are you overiding the onDestroy method? If so show us your code...well...show us your code anyways cant figure it out like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the splash screen automatically start the Menu Actvity?    If it does you may want to start the MenuActivity by using `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`.  Then in the Menu activity override `onBackPressed` and pass back a code letting the Main Activity know to `finish();` and handle it using `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

This link on the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) should help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. That's not quite what I was going for but it doesn't matter since I've decided to just hijack the back button on the main menu and have it exit the game. No real need to head back to the splash screen anyways.

Comment: Typically in this situation you would just have the splash screen activity call startActivity() of the next activity and then immediately finish() on itself.  This is actually a somewhat common pattern in regular apps, where you have an initial activity that decides based on data in a shared preference or elsewhere the "real" first activity for the user to see.

Comment: @hackbod Thanks so much for that suggestion I tried it out and it's doing exactly what I want it to now.